# How to measure data quality?

Tags: null, data-cleaning, data-quality

I have a question regarding data quality. I am aware of the data quality dimensions, but I'd like to be able to measure data quality in numbers.
For example how many NULL are acceptable in a column e.g. 2%, 5%, 10% etc.
I know every data set is unique and there is not a one-fits-all solution, but it would great if someone knows a resource where they have published measurable guidelines.

Comment: Could be helpful to know the purpose of that data quality assessment.